# jQuery, I want an explanation. Why does this work? $($('div'))

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm curious. This:

```
$('div'), this $($('div')), and this $($($('div')))... and so on
```

Seem to all work as selectors for HTML elements. Does anyone know why this works, and if there are any actual (besides redundancy), problems that arise when doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/NpT2b/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jQuery function can take an existing jQuery object as its argument. This is documented and intentional behavior. Take a look at the manual here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

It's also not specific to HTML elements. `$( $('#foo') )` would work.

One reason for this which I've exploited in the past is to let a function accept ***either*** a selector ***or*** a jQuery object. So I could write a function:

```
function excite(target) {
    $(target).append(' This is exciting!');
};
```

This is safe to call with `excite('.foo');` or with `excite( $('p:not(.exciting-already)').empty() );`

Comment: Very good explanation. Kudos for pointing out that the object is actually cloned. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

If jQuery receives a jQuery object, it doesn't need to do anything and so returns the jQuery object untouched.

This is usually to deal with unscrupulous coders, who might accidentally put a jQuery object back through `$()`

Comment: I suppose that's because there's nothing unscrupulous in putting a jQuery object through `$()`. It's a) unavoidable in the broader view of things and b) one of the reasons why jQuery works so well.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but according to the documentation the object is actually cloned, not returned untouched. This would matter, for example, if I did `var a = $('p'); var b = $(a); b.add('td');`

Comment: @Elliot That doesn't mean I made the downvote, I'm just pointing out the one disputable statement in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors take either strings, HTML elements, or other jQuery objects as selectors. In this case, your first example selects all `<div>` elements on the page. In your second example, you're re-selecting the jQuery set of all `<div>` elements. In your third example, you're re-re-selecting the set. This can continue indefinitely without any problems besides utter and complete redundancy.